# How to use sprintf to append array of uint_64 type to an array of char?

Tags: c++, c, printf

I want to append the data in `ID[10]` to `dispvar` using sprintf. But the problem is that ID is of `uint64_t` type and `dispvar` is of type `char`. So when I try the below code, I get only the first value stored in `ID` appended to `dispvar`. How can I append the entire content of `ID` to `dispvar`?

```
char dispvar[150]={0};

union Device_Details{
    struct DeviceDetails{
        uint64_t FirmwareID[10];
        uint64_t No_of_Mot;
        uint64_t ID[10];
        uint64_t RTC_Data[7];
        uint64_t BatStat;       
    }Device;
    uint64_t Buffer[11];
}DeviceData;

sprintf(dispvar,"\n Device ID is %s", ( char *)ID);
```

ID is set from my app, so if I set ID as Hello from my app, ID will look like - ID[0]='H',ID[1] = 'e',ID[2] = 'l', ID[3] = 'l', ID[4] = '0'; each of them is index of unsigned long long type.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkReg.jpg)

Comment: Why the cast to `char*` and the use of `%s`? Are you saying that `ID` holds string data really even though it is declared as `uint64_t[10]`?

Comment: `using sprintf.` - The data are numbers between 0 and 2^64 - 1. In what _format_ do you want to store the data? As a string representing a binary number? As a string with a base 10 number? As a string with a hexadecimal number? As a string with a octal numbers? Or do you want to copy the bytes that consist of the number exactly into other memory address?

Comment: ID is set from my app, so if I set ID as Hello from my app, ID will look like -   ID[0]='H', ID[1] = 'e',ID[2] = 'l', ID[3] = 'l', ID[4] = '0'; each of them is index is unsigned long long

Comment: @blazingcannon This information should be in the question. It's vital to understand what you want to do.

Comment: @KamilCuk - Like I've given an example above, I just want Hello to get appended to my dispvar as characters.

Comment: Can you give example input and example output? As in `ID[0] = 48, ID[1] = 49, ID[3] = 50` and `dispvar="123"` ? [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: The whole point of using sprintf is for it to do the string conversion. If the data was in string format in the first place, you wouldn't need it. Thus the `%s` format specifier and the `char*` cast is nonsense. The correct format specifier to use for printing uint64_t is `"%"PRIu64` from inttypes.h.

Comment: @Lundin But (for some unknown reason) the OP really does have character data in the ID array

Comment: `auto p = dispvar + sprintf(dispvar, "\n Device ID is ");
std::copy(std::begin(ID), std::end(ID), p);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little need for conversion, because the data are stored in `uint64_t` array.

```
// first populate the dispvar with initial string
int idx = sprintf(dispvar, "\n Device ID is ");

// we have the array
uint64_t ID[10] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
// for each element in ID
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(ID)/sizeof(*ID); ++i) {
      // assert(isprint(ID[i])); // extra assertion
      // we put the ID[i] into our dispvar
      dispvar[idx++] = ID[i];
      // null terminte character is also copied. We need to break.
      if (ID[i] == '\0') {
           break;
      }
}

// should work as expected
printf("%s\n", dispvar);
```

There is no way you could do this using `sprintf`. You also can copy the array into a char buffer manually and then call `sprintf`.

Comment: The `if (ID[i] == '\0')` shouldn't be necessary. If it was, you should iterate `while(ID[i] != '\0')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The ID values apparently contain character data with a terminating zero, at least that's what I'm assuming below.

```
char buffer[11];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    buffer[i] = ID[i];
buffer[10] = '\0';
sprintf(dispvar,"\n Device ID is %s", buffer);
```